# Combining 2 rows into 1 by using self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Following simplified table

```
CustNr OrderNr Date    Price Curry
1      555     030316  2,4   EUR
1      666     030316  2,5   EUR
1      777     030316  2,3   EUR
1      777     030316  1,9   USD
1      888     030316  2,3   EUR
1      888     030316  2,4   EUR
```

Desired output:

```
CustNr OrderNr Date    Price Curry   CustNr OrderNr Date    Price Curry
1      555     030316  2,4   EUR
1      666     030316  2,5   EUR
1      777     030316  2.3   EUR     1      777     030316   1,9   USD
1      888     030316  2,3   EUR     1      888     030316   2,4   EUR
```

I tried following self join:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST T1 INNER JOIN TEST T2 ON T1.OrderNr = T2.OrderNr
```

But then i get duplicate records and a `GROUP BY` only works when grouping by OrderNr but I also need the other columns aswell.

Comment: And what result would you want if you had triple or quadruple records?

Comment: For this scenario I have it is not possible that triple or quadruple records exist

Comment: And what makes a row appear on the left vs. on the right side?  Is it based on the currency, price, some other criteria?  When you have duplicates, is it always a `EUR` vs. `USD` duplicate? I think you're omitting important details.

Comment: will CustNr OrderNr ever repeat more than twice?

Comment: @sstan It is not relevant which goes left or right or what currency, if there are recordes with duplicate OrderNumbers then 2 rows should be in a single row.

Comment: @Matt it is not possible that OrderNr ever repeats more than twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like your question is not 100% clear.  But based on your current description, this query should work:

```
with cte as (
  select CustNr, OrderNr, Date, Price, Curry,
         row_number() over (partition by OrderNr order by OrderNr) as rn
    from test
)
select t1.CustNr, t1.OrderNr, t1.Date, t1.Price, t1.Curry,
       t2.CustNr, t2.OrderNr, t2.Date, t2.Price, t2.Curry
  from cte t1
  left join cte t2
    on t2.OrderNr = t1.OrderNr
   and t2.rn = 2
 where t1.rn = 1
```

With the above query, which rows appear on the left vs. right hand side is completely arbitrary.  If you want to define which row goes where, you can do that by adjusting the `order by` clause in the `row_number` window function.

Answer (score 4):

Need to number rows with the same OrderNr some way.

```
with tn as (
    select *, rn=row_number() over(partition by OrderNr order by Price)
    from table
)
select t1.*, t2.*
from tn t1
left join tn t2 on t2.OrderNr = t1.OrderNr and t2.rn=2
where t1.rn=1
```

Comment: This  solved my problem thank you alot, I have changed the Order by Price part to order by OrderNr, as for me it is not relevant how the rows appear

Answer (score 1):

You should use left  join  instead of inner join  and filter by Curry

```
SELECT * FROM TEST T1 LEFT JOIN TEST T2 ON (T1.OrderNr = T2.OrderNr
AND  T1.Curry <> T2.Curry )
```

Comment: I think this will work with the exact example given, but if the currency changes it wouldn't.

Comment: But there might  also exist records that have duplicates with totally differents currencies for example CHF, RMB etc.

Comment: @Mance but you have two or more different Curry ?  And you can have more than a row for difference curry?

Comment: @mance in that case, of more Currencies, are you saying you want more columns?  Or more rows of the combinations, and how do you want to choose the main/1st currency.  I missed the EUR but yeah that should be ON .. AND t1.curry <> t2.Curry

Comment: If you use only two curry  .. cab be solved with T1.curry!= t2.curry ..

Answer (score 0):

You need a top-level query that represents unique order numbers:

```
select 
t.OrderNr,
t1.*,
t2.*
from (select distinct OrderNr from test) t
cross apply (select top 1 * from test t1 where t1.OrderNr = t.OrderNr order by Curry) t1
outer apply (select top 1 * from test t2 where t2.OrderNr = t.OrderNr and t2.Curry <> t1.Curry order by Curry) t2
```

I think this answers the question, but I think it raises more questions about the design of the desired output.

Comment: This looks good but if the Currency in the duplicate records is the same I get only NULL Values on the 2nd columns, I have adapted the output in the description I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Ah got it.  Then @Serg covers that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (
  CustNr int,
  OrderNr int,
  Date int,
  Price varchar(20),
  Curry char(3)
);
INSERT INTO @tab
  VALUES (1, 555, 030316, '2,4', 'EUR'),
  (1, 666, 030316, '2,5', 'EUR'),
  (1, 777, 030316, '2,3', 'EUR'),
  (1, 777, 030316, '1,9', 'USD'),
  (1, 888, 030316, '2,3', 'EUR'),
  (1, 888, 030316, '2,4', 'EUR');

SELECT
  T1.custNr,
  T1.OrderNr,
  T1.date,
  T1.price,
  T1.curry,
  T2.custNr,
  T2.OrderNr,
  T2.date,
  T2.price,
  T2.curry
FROM (SELECT
  T1.custNr,
  T1.OrderNr,
  T1.date,
  T1.price,
  T1.curry,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.custNr,
  T1.OrderNr ORDER BY T1.custNr,
  T1.OrderNr) AS [rank1]
FROM @tab T1) T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  (custNr) AS custNr,
  OrderNr,
  (date) AS date,
  (price) AS price,
  (curry) AS curry,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custNr,
  OrderNr ORDER BY custNr,
  OrderNr) AS [rank]
FROM @tab T2) T2
  ON T1.OrderNr = T2.OrderNr
  AND T2.rank > 1
WHERE T1.rank1 <> 2
ORDER BY T1.OrderNr;
```